# TypeError: source.split is not a function. (In 'source.split('\n')', 'source.split' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error while working in react native I don't know why this is happening. I am getting this error and then the app reloads automatically. I think this used in some packages. I didn't use any split function in my app.

```
[Mon Dec 28 2020 00:06:36.425]  ERROR    TypeError: source.split is not a function. (In 'source.split('\n')', 'source.split' is undefined)     

This error is located at:
    in SvgXml (at register.js:214)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at register.js:213)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at register.js:212)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at register.js:198)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
........................
..........
...........
    in Root (at connectStyle.js:392)
    in Styled(Root) (at RootComponent.js:7)
    in RootComponent (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Comment: Please also post the code where you called it.

Comment: I told you i didn't use this function. This is may be in any package I am using. The app was working fine but after I update the code and then suddenly this msg start coming

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/1299   The same issue I think this is in SvgXml package

Comment: I think i got it my bad I am using the 2 variables with same name one is the svg image and one is the state variable.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this error in my app and it was related to lib `react-native-svg`
specifically because I haven't added a configuration to use svgXml.